# Loop Over Python Dictionary (using C API) Twice?

Tags: python-c-api

I'm currently writing a Python module in C. In it, I have a dictionary that I iterate over like so:

```
PyObject *key, *value;
Py_ssize_t pos = 0;

while (PyDict_Next(index, &pos, &key, &value))
    /* do interesting things here */
```

Later in the same method, I then want to loop over the dictionary again. However, `PyDict_Next(...)` continues to return `NULL`. Is there any way to reset the internal iteration counter used by `PyDict_Next(...)`?

Comment: I think you just set pos to zero again.

Comment: Yup, looks like you are correct! I just discovered that a few hours ago, in fact. If you want to write that as an answer I'll accept it. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The iterator is initialized by setting pos to 0. You can restart the iterator by setting pos to 0 again.

```
PyObject *key, *value;
Py_ssize_t pos = 0;

while (PyDict_Next(index, &pos, &key, &value))
    /* do interesting things here */

pos = 0;

while (PyDict_Next(index, &pos, &key, &value))
    /* do even more interesting things here */
```